# Calling unmanaged code from ASP.NET in IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, c++, iis-7, unmanaged

I call a DLL in ASP.NET a DLL that is written in C++.
When running it into IIS 7, The pool (w3wp.exe) crash and the "just in time debugging window" open.

I do many tracing and I found that crash happen when calling any function (in the unmanaged DLLs) that have a "out string" parameter (or return a string value).

I saw on the web than many people have this problem with their DLL (C, Delphi, VB6). But no answer. so I call experts!

How can I call these functions so IIS 7 process it without error ?

cas sakal

Comment: ANSWER: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/832054-error-using-unmanaged-c-ocx-c-net Based upon this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189065/en-us This is a horribly tough problem. Get the word out on it. The issue is that if the ActiveX control is not embedded in the calling process (as it is not when called from ASP running in IIS), it isn't initialized and therefore needs a hack.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `StringBuilder` for interop string output parameters:

```
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder myString
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be possible. COM provides an interface specification, but not a guarantee that the caller be able to use the interface correctly. Unless the COM object exposes methods which are automatically marshalable by the COM subsystem (eg: automation compatible), you may not be able to use them. It's easily possible to write a C++ COM object which cannot be directly accessed out-of-process, or by any language other than C++.

You may be able to write some custom marshaling code to make it work, but I wouldn't assume it will work directly. If the types are simple/direct enough, there may be some built-in marshal attributes to make it work; I don't have a lot of knowledge in this area, though, so hopefully other people can help out.